# tycho error: [cannot determine filter for requirement for this element]

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have an eclipse RCP application. I have been trying to generate a zip with executable for Windows using tycho. I am able to build eclipse-plugin projects successfully but while publishing product I get an error:

"included element org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64.source 0.0.0 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element."

I checked my plugins folder in C:\eclipse\plugins and I see that I have a org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64.source_3.103.1.v20140903-1947. I am not sure where is tycho getting the version as 0.0.0 from?

I followed http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp04-rcp for writing POM's since my project structure is very similar except that I have eclipse plugins instead of features. 
Thank you.